# How to use parent div font color instead of child

Tags: css

I have a dropdown menu with some options inside of it. An option has 2 text, text1 and text2.

Take a look at simplified code below to see what happens when an option is hovered:

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <style>
        .hh1 { color: purple !important; }
        .hh2 { color: green; }
        .hh3 { color: red; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="hh1">
    <div class="hh2">
        test1
    </div>
    <div class="hh3">
        test2
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Expected behaviour when an option is not hovered, it will be the color defined in its div (in this case, text1 is green and text2 is red. When it is hovered, it will be the one defined in its parent div, in this case purple.

I am surprised !important in the code above does not make test1 and test2 in purple color.
How can I emphasis the purple rule ? 
Thank you

Comment: you didn't define any hover effect

Comment: Hover in CSS looks like this`.hh2:hover{color: purple}` so you need to use `:hover` to show what you want to happen when a hover interaction happens to that class element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

`!important` only affects the cascade. It cannot force the value of a child element's property to become `inherit`.

If you want to change the colour of a child element, then you must match it explicitly.

e.g.

```
.hh1, .hh1 > .hh2 { color: purple; }
```

Comment: oh I just realized that if I add : .hh1 * { color: purple !important; } it will change to purple. is this a good solution too?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't put any hover effects in your style tag That's why your hover effect isn't applied.

Take a look I have made changes to your code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <style>
        .hh1 { color: purple !important; }
        .hh2 { color: green; }
        .hh3 { color: red; }
      .hh2:hover {
        color: purple;
      }
      .hh3:hover {
        color: purple;
      }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="hh1">
    <div class="hh2">
        test1
    </div>
    <div class="hh3">
        test2
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: better use `color:inherit` to avoid the repeat of purple and make the color of the parent useful

Comment: This can also be written as `.hh2:hover, .hh3:hover {color: purple;}` you use the `,` to say this class and this class use this colour

Answer (score 0):

Use `color:inherit` on `:hover` , also you can write your `:hover` effect in one line.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <style>
        .hh1 { color: purple !important; }
        .hh2 { color: green; }
        .hh3 { color: red; }
      .hh2:hover , .hh3:hover {
        color: inherit;
      }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="hh1">
    <div class="hh2">
        test1
    </div>
    <div class="hh3">
        test2
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```